# Parity wallet freezes on first setup page on Mac osx

Tags: parity, mac-osx

I'm trying to install parity for a mate on his name Mac. After the install, on the first setup page where it asks me to put in my wallet name etc, it freezes on that table only. I've left it for an hour thinking maybe it was syncing but that didn't help. Reinstalled 3 times. We both don't know how to do anything technical on a Mac so sorry for the simple noon technical explanation.

Comment: That's a known issue. Try to leave it like that over night if you have the chance and check back in the morning.